# An unknown element style

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on my UI with datatable from bootstrap, I think the unknown element has something to do with it.

[image]

Where is that element from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`element.style` means the style is applied inline to the element, either manually or dynamically via JS

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am confused here. As far as I know, no element is <element> in html and I also checked my code, I didn't see anything having something to do with "element".

Comment: element refers to any html element, such as `div`, `p`, in your case is the `ul`, look at your left  in Screenshot it is selected

Comment: How can I remove the style added on this element? I checked my js code, I don't add this.

Answer (score 1):

That `element` is referring to the element currently highlighted and `style` attribute for it.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS under `element.style` means it is inline style. Inline styles are often set through javascript. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

element.style means inline style. its quite possible that it might be applied via javascript. please search ID mentioned in JS file

by the way check top comment its says this come after receiving data

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used ajax to dynamically generate items in a navbar. But what i don't understand is <element> doesn't exist in html, how come it appears...

Comment: Actually using javascript we can create DOM element `document.createElement( "div" )`  or we can use  `.append()` and `.prepend()` to add Dom element. 


please visit here http://api.jquery.com/append/